# Angular sort toggle not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
$scope.searchObject = {
  from: 0,
  hydrate: false,
  size: 12,
  sort: 'timestamp:desc'
};

$scope.sort = function(a) {
  var ascend = a + ':' + 'asc';
  var descend = a + ':' + 'desc';
  if ($scope.searchObject.sort === ascend) {
    $scope.searchObject.sort = descend;
  }
  if ($scope.searchObject.sort === descend) {
    console.log('is desc')
    $scope.searchObject.sort = ascend;
    console.log('sort : ', $scope.searchObject.sort)
  } else {
    $scope.searchObject.sort = descend;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="sort-info">
  <label>Sort:</label>
  <a class="sort-item" ng-click="sort('timestamp')"> Date
      <div class="sort-arrow" >
        <i ng-show="searchObject.sort === 'timestamp:asc'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <i ng-show="searchObject.sort === 'timestamp:desc'" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  <a class="sort-item" ng-click="sort('followers')">Followers
     <div class="sort-arrow">
       <i ng-show="searchObject.sort === 'followers:asc'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       <i ng-show="searchObject.sort === 'followers:desc'" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
     </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Once it the sort hits desc again, it will not switch back to asc. The conditional is being triggered, and it console.logs the appropriate sort within search object, but the view isn't changed.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker demonstrating your bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need an `else if`

```
$scope.sort = function (a) {
    var ascend = a + ':' + 'asc';
    var descend = a + ':' + 'desc';
    if ($scope.searchObject.sort === ascend) {
      $scope.searchObject.sort = descend;
    }else if ($scope.searchObject.sort === descend){
      console.log('is desc')
      $scope.searchObject.sort = ascend;
      console.log('sort : ', $scope.searchObject.sort)
    }
    else {
      $scope.searchObject.sort = descend;
    }
  };
```